# synchronizing processes with alarms in c

Tags: c, process, signals, alarm

I have to write a program about signals and alarms, and i can't use semaphores
A first process (named "B") launches another one (named "A"). "A" have to write random words in a file, once per 5 secs, if it writes the word END  terminates the execution. The process "B" have to read the words from the file, if read END then relaunch the process "A". When "B" reads 50 words kills "A" and terminates the execution

The program does not work properly,I think it's because both processes accessing the file at the same time, but I do not know for sure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SECS 5
#define MAX_READ 50
#define MAX_TAM 10
#define N_WORDS 13

int main(void){
    int i=0,flag;
    pid_t pid;
    static char words[][MAX_TAM]={"THE","PROCESS","A","WRITES","IN","A","FILE","WORDS","AND","KILL","ITSELF","WITH","END"};
    char *word; 
    char read[MAX_TAM];
    FILE *fp=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    if(!fp){
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR){
        puts("Error");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1){
        flag=0;
        switch(pid=fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("fork error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case 0: /* A  */
                srand(getpid());
                while(1){
                    if(alarm(SECS))
                        pause();       
                    word = words[rand()%N_WORDS];       
                    fprintf(fp,"%s ",word);
                    printf("A ~ WORD: %s\n",word);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    if(!strcmp(word,"END")){
                        fclose(fp);
                        printf("ENDING A\n");
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    }       
                }
            default: /* Proceso B */
                sleep(1);
                for( ;i<MAX_READ;i++){
                    if(alarm(SECS))
                        pause();
                    fscanf(fp,"%s",read);
                    printf("B ~ READING %s\n",read);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    if(!strcmp(read,"END")){
                        flag=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        if(flag==0)
            break;
    }
    kill(pid,9);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: this line `if(flag=0)break;` contains a coding error (that is why the literal should always be on the left, so the compiler catches these kinds of errors)  the line should be: `if( 0 == flag ) break;`  BTW: it is always a good idea, for readability, to incorporate appropriate horizontal spacing

Comment: thanks  user3629249,  it was a problem copying the code in the page

Comment: in the `case` code blocks, in a `switch()` statement it is always best practice to include the `break;` statement at the end of the `case` code block, even if the code block contains `exit()` or `return;` statements

Comment: Per the man page for `signal()` "Avoid its use: use sigaction() instead."

Comment: the easiest (and IMO: best way is via a copy and paste operation to put the code into the question.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("B ~ READING %s\n",read);`  since the format string ends with `\n`, the output will be automatically flushed to stdout, so no need to call `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: suggest re-reading the man page for `pause()` it does not work quite like the posted code seems to think.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I'll try another approach to do it

Comment: regarding this line: `fscanf(fp,"%s",read);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter) value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always use a max length modifier (which has to be 1 less than the length of the input buffer `read[]` because with'%s' the scanf() function will always append a NUL byte.) Suggest: `fscanf(fp,"%9s",read);`  However, '%s' will not scan beyond any white space, so the line should be: `fscanf(fp," %9s",read);` (note leading space in format string)

Comment: the variable `flag` is being improperly handled, so the code always stays in the `while()` loop, forever.    Also, there is no counting of the number of words read by 'B', so there is no indication when to exit the whole program.  To start, suggest initialining `flag` during its' declaration, then using `while( !flag )` then 'B' only changes flag when 50 words read, but exits its' `for` loop when 'END' read.  (instead of `for(), it should be: `while( strcmp( word, "END" ) )